# Erro na impressão dos dados

Tags: c

exemplo de entrada:

```
rmtpuzcafhnyxdesivlkbwgjqo
2
roahp
uhchch
```

saida :

```
veras
batata
```

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char palavra[ 1000 ];
    char alfabeto[ 26 ];
    char codificacao[ 1000 ];
    int N, i, tam, j, indice;

    scanf( "%s", alfabeto );

    scanf( "%d", &N );

    for( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    {
        scanf( "%s", palavra );
    }

    tam = strlen( palavra );

    for( j = 0; j < tam; j++ )
    {
        palavra[ j ] = toupper( palavra[ j ] );
        indice = palavra[ j ] - 65;
        codificacao[ j ] = alfabeto[ indice ];
    }
    printf( "%s\n", codificacao );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: seu print deve estar dentro do for

Comment: Quando coloco ele dentro do for, ele printa caractere por caractere da ultima saida, no caso, b,ba,bat,bata,batat,batata...

Comment: não sei como é feito em C, porém, você pode dentro do seu for, concatenar as strings e inserir em uma variável, assim, no fim, fora do for, printe o resultado

Answer (score 1):

Você lê N vezes a string palavra e sobrepõe todas as leituras, por isso só vai tratar a última.
Para tratar palavra a palavra faça:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
/*exemplo de entrada

rmtpuzcafhnyxdesivlkbwgjqo
2
roahp
uhchch

saida
veras
batata
*/


int main(){
    char palavra[1000];
    char alfabeto[26];
    char codificacao[1000];
    int N, i, tam, j, indice;
    scanf("%s", alfabeto);
    scanf("%d", &N);
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        scanf("%s", palavra);
        tam = strlen(palavra);
        for(j = 0; j < tam; j++){
            palavra[j] = toupper(palavra[j]);
            indice = palavra[j] - 65;
            codificacao[j] = alfabeto[indice];
        }
        printf("%s\n", codificacao);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mt obg mano, mas agr a cada entrada ele já dá a saida, como faço pra botar tds entradas e printar as saidas só dps?

Comment: usa o printf fora do for

Comment: Neste caso você precisará fazer alocação dinâmica para alocar memória para guardar as N palavras de entrada juntamente com as N codificações de saída, e só imprimir todas as codificações ao final.

Comment: Não posso usar alocação dinâmica

Comment: A cada leitura, trate a palavra lida, grave a saída em um arquivo e ao final do tratamento de todas as palavras imprima todo o arquivo.

Comment: Dependendo dos limites que a variável N puder assumir você pode definir uma string bastante grande e colocar cada codificação nesta string, seguida de um caractere '\n' e imprimir tal string ao final. Mas esta solução não será geral.

Comment: Neste caso o ideal é, a cada entrada, você verificar se existe espaço na string para armazenar a saída codificada.

Comment: Como eu faço isso??

Comment: Supondo que você vá concatenar as codificações em uma string denominada saida de dimensão TAM_MAX, faça o seguinte teste:
if (TAM_MAX - strlen(saida) > strlen(codificacao)) {
 strcat(saida, codificacao);
 strcat(saida, "\n");
}
else {
 print("Erro. Não comporta a string.\n");
 exit(1);
}